# How to handle public view-modifying viewcontroller properties?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I often find myself in the situation where I have a property in a viewcontroller, the value of which affects part of the viewcontroller's view.

As an example, let's say that the boolean property **flag** determines whether the view **flagView** should be hidden or not.

Now, **flag** can be set either before or after **flagView** has loaded.

If I set flag after flagView has been loaded, then it makes sense to implement *didSet* for **flag** and set the *.hidden* property of **flagView** there, however this will break if **flag** is set before **flagView** has loaded.

You can use *isViewLoaded* to avoid that, but then you are forced to also set **flagView**.hidden in the viewControllers *viewDidLoad* method.

I would like to avoid the need to set the *.hidden* property in two separate places, are there any good practices/patterns for this?

Code for illustration:

```
var flag = false {
    didSet {
        if isViewLoaded() {
            flagView.hidden = flag
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flagView.hidden = flag
}
```

Comment: i think this is pretty much the way you have to do it, maybe there is some key-value observing hackery you could use, but i think it would end up the same essentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `flag` property to itself in `viewDidLoad` to trigger `didSet` to do its job.  Swift apparently doesn't account for side effects and tries to prevent you from doing this *"no-operation"* assignment, but you can work around that by setting:

```
flag = (flag)  // trigger didSet
```

This keeps your action code inside of `didSet` and doesn't litter `viewDidLoad` with the details of what happens.  This is especially true if `didSet` is more complicated than just one line.

```
var flag = false {
    didSet {
        if isViewLoaded() {
            flagView.hidden = flag
            // do additional actions when flag is set ...
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flag = (flag)  // trigger didSet
}
```